# How to disable SSL in JAVA_OPTS in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ssl, kubernetes, fabric8

I am running Kubernetes API to access a kubernetes cluster. The connection fails with teh following error 
 `javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?`

The kubernetes endpoint is http and not https. How do I make sure that this is configured in the JAVA_OPTS for eclipse>?

Comment: Why is the endpoint http? Are you running the local docker example?

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you tried to access the wrong port.

By default, a secure port is opened on 6443. You should be able to make an SSL connection to that port:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/54706661ad72d62ea0b494112a74e0467093c9f4/cmd/kube-apiserver/app/server.go#L128

For up-to-date information about how to access the API, please take a look at the documentation:
http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/accessing-the-cluster.html
http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/admin/accessing-the-api.html

If more information would be useful there, please file an issue requesting the specific information you would expect to see in the documentation.
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/new